# Why does ln n use root n as a direct comparison?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(\ln n)}{n^2}
$$

*Use the direct comparison test*

My teachers solution is:

$\frac{(\ln n)}{n^2} < \frac{\sqrt n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}}$ and so it converges because p-series > 1

How does the direct comparison go from $\ln n$ to $\sqrt n$?

Comment: The given series is actually related with $\zeta'(2)$ and the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**

For $x\geq 4$, put

$$f (x)=\ln (x)-\sqrt{x}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac {2-\sqrt {x}}{2x}\leq 0$$

thus $f $ is decreasing at $[4,+\infty). $

For   enough great $n $, we have

$$f (n)\leq f (4)=\ln (4)-2\leq 0$$
and
$$\ln (n)\leq \sqrt {n} .$$

we also use this to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {\ln (n)}{n}=0.$$

Answer (score 3):

For every $n\geq 1$
$$\log(n) = \int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x} \stackrel{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}}{\leq} \sqrt{\int_{1}^{n}dx \int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x^2}} \leq \sqrt{n-1} $$
for instance.

Comment: Cute. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use a larger function so that you know that if the larger one converges, then the smaller one does too.

$\sqrt{n}$ is chosen because it is easy to prove that it is smaller.

**Proof:**

Let: 
$$f(x)=\sqrt x - \ln(x)$$

We must prove that $f(x)>0, \forall x$.

Note that: 
$$f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}-2}{2x}$$

The minimum of the function is when $f'(x)=0$ or when $f'(x)$ is undefined, which is when $x=0$ or: 
$$0=\sqrt{x}-2 \Leftrightarrow 2=\sqrt{x}\Leftrightarrow{x=4}$$

So our possible minimums are $0$ and $4$. One is undefined (in fact, heading toward it leads to positive infinity) and the other is positive, so both our possible minimums are positive, proving that $ln(x)<\sqrt(x)$ for all $x$.

A similar argument can be used for all $x^a, a>0$. This follows as a direct consequence of $e^x$ eventually being *bigger* than all $x^a, a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

As the others point out, the logarithm is eventually smaller than any fixed power.

What holds for all $x > 0$ is $e^x \geq x^e,$ with equality at $x=e.$
Let's prove that, why not. Let
$$ f(x) = \ln \frac{x^e}{e^x} = e \ln x - x. $$
$$ f'(x) = \frac{e}{x} - 1. $$
So $f'(x)$ is positive for $0 < x < e$ and negative for $x > e.$ Therefore the maximum of $f(x)$ occurs at $x=e.$

So
$$ \ln x \leq x^{1/e},  $$
with equality at $x = e^e \approx 15.154.$

It follows immediately that, for $x > e^e,$ we have $\ln x < \sqrt x.$ A little more work on small values shows that, when $x > 0,$ we get
$$  \ln x < \sqrt x $$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Jack D'Aurizio's answer:

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(n)
&=\int_1^n \frac{dx}{x}\\
&\lt\int_1^n \frac{dx}{x^{1-c}}
\qquad\text{for any } c > 0\\
&=\int_1^n x^{c-1}dx\\
&=\frac{x^c}{c}\big|_1^n\\
&=\frac{n^c-1}{c}\\
&\lt\frac{n^c}{c}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
for any
$0 < c < 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(\ln n)}{n^2}
&\lt \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n^c}{cn^2}\\
&= \frac1{c}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^{2-c}}\\
\end{array}
$

and this converges by
any test you want
(comparison, preferably).

Answer (score 0):

In response to Thomas Andrews' comment, I will provide a proof for $\ln x$ growing slower than $x^\alpha$ for all $\alpha >0$, i.e.,

$$ \lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^\alpha} < 1, \quad \alpha >0.$$

Note that the actual limit is zero, but it is not our goal here.

Let

$$
\begin{align}
y &= \frac{\ln x}{x^\alpha}, \quad x > 0,\;\alpha > 0, \quad (1) \\
y' &= \frac{1-\alpha \ln x}{x^{\alpha+1}}, \quad (2)\\
y' &=0 \implies x = c = e^{1/\alpha}.
\end{align}
$$

Note:

- $y'(c) = 0$ and $c > 1$ for all $\alpha > 0$.
- The sign of $y'(x)$ is unchanged in either side of $x=c$:

  - Pick $x=1$ on the left of $c: y'(1) = 1 > 0$ so that $y'(x) > 0$ for $x < c.$
  - Pick $x=2c$ on the right of $c$:
    $$ y'(2c) = \frac{-\ln 2}{\left(2e^{1/\alpha}\right)^{\alpha+1}} < 0.$$

Thus, the function $y(x)$ is strictly increasing for $0 < x < c$, reaching the maximum at $x=c$ where

$$ y_{max} = \frac{\ln e^{1/\alpha}}{(e^{1/\alpha})^\alpha} = \frac{1}{\alpha e},\quad (3)$$
and strictly decreasing for $c < x < +\infty$.

Now that we know that $y$ is strictly decreasing on the right of $c$, we will show that we can find $x=\lambda$ such that $0 < y < 1$ for all $x > \lambda$. There are two cases:

A) For $\alpha \ge e^{-1}:\;$

In this case, $ \alpha e \ge 1 $, and $ (3)$ gives $0 < y_{max} \le 1$. Hence, we can pick any $\lambda > c$, where $c > 1$ as mentioned above.

B) For $0 < \alpha < e^{-1}:$

Pick $\lambda = e^\alpha > 1:$

$$ y(\lambda) = \frac{\ln x}{x^\alpha}\bigg|_{x=\lambda} = \frac{\alpha}{e^{2\alpha}} < 1$$
because the numerator is already less than $1$, and the denominator is always greater than $1$.

Thus, we have shown that we can always pick up a value of $\lambda$ such that for all $x > \lambda > 1,\, y$ becomes less than $1$, i.e., $\ln x$ is always less than $x^\alpha$ for all $\alpha > 0$ when $x\to+\infty$.

Answer (score -1):

It is a well known fact that $y=\ln x$ is always growing at a slower rate than $f(x)=x^\alpha$ for all values of $\alpha\gt0$ as $x\to+\infty$. It is straightforward to prove this fact.

Thus, your teacher could have chosen $\alpha = 0.0001$, for instance. The choice of $\alpha = 1/2$ is just a convenience because she could then obtain an inequality for all values of $n\ge 1$.

Comment: -1 for starting an answer with "It is well known that..." and never showing why.

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews, I merely tried to provide a quick explanation for what the teacher did, and I was careful in adding that "It is straightforward to prove this fact" so that Kyle could proceed to prove if necessary.